# Mailchimp http 200 when already subscribed

Tags: php, json, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Though I found a few clues to this problem, I still can't get the final solution.
Why do I keep getting http result code 200, even when an e-mail address is already on list. So no code 214 is returned.
Now the data is overwriting existing, which I would like to avoid.
thank you

```html
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $listID = 'xxxxxxx';
        
        // MailChimp API URL
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;
        
        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields'  => [
                'FNAME'     => $fname,
                'LNAME'     => $lname
            ]
        ]);
        
        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        $_SESSION['code'] = $httpCode;
        // store the status message based on response code
        if ($httpCode == 200) {
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: red">You have successfully subscribed.</p>';
        } else {
            switch ($httpCode) {
                case 214:
                    $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                    break;
                default:
                    $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                    break;
            }
            $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: red">'.$msg.'</p>';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
    }
}
// redirect to prev page
header('location:index.php');
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to add that `$memberID` at the end of your request url? I don't have a lot of experience with the mailchimp api but just from checking the documentation it seems that adding the userID at the end will do a status check and omitting it will actually add it to the list.  https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/

Comment: Also make sure you're actually sending a POST request by adding: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: Hallo Dirk, dank. I tried both options. Removing '$memberID' gives a 405 (Method not allowed); the second makes no difference in the result. I keep getting a '200' server response. Will perform a few other tests.

Comment: Having a bit more time to research Dirk Scholten was correct. His remarks did the trick. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: @numbernine could you share your updated code by chance? I tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` as mentioned above but I am still getting a 200 success response on duplicate e-mails.

Comment: hi, the main mods I did was: I replaced  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
by
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
    // MailChimp API credentials
    $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $listID = 'xxxxxxx';
    
    // MailChimp API URL
    $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;
    
    // member information
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email
       ]);
            // send a HTTP POST request with curl
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 //mod start
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 //mod end
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    
   $_SESSION['code'] = $httpCode;
    // store the status message based on response code
    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #34A853">E-mail address already on list. ('.$_SESSION['code']. ')</p>';
    } else {
        switch ($httpCode) {
            //case 214:
            case 404:
                $msg = 'E-mail address not yet on list. ('.$_SESSION['code']. ')</p>';
                break;
            default:
                $msg = 'Error. Pls try again. ('.$_SESSION['code']. ')</p>';
                break;
        }
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
}
}
// redirect to prev page
echo $httpCode;
//echo $result ;
//echo $url;
header('location:add.php');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.